# bash - passing a pattern including wildcards as a parameter to recursive function

Tags: bash, function, wildcard, ls, expansion

I am still quite confused with the way variables expand. This is my code:

```
if [ "$2" ]; then
  pattern="*$2*"
else
  pattern=""
fi

function list(){
  ls -lF $2 > output_file
  for dir in `ls -d1 */`; do
     list "$dir" $2
  done
}
cd $1; path=`basename $PWD`
list "$path" $pattern
```

This script attempts to store some file information for the files contained in $1 whose names containt a string given in $2. 
The main purpose is just learning, and the specific error I want to avoid is the one I get when wildcard characters stored in pattern are interpreted as a file name.

find, stat, and using the pattern without ls can get the desired output (And I'll be glad to learn the most elegant way. BUT the main question here is how to handle wildcard characters if you'd want to pass them as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Double quote the variable where the value shouldn't be expanded:

```
list "$dir" "$2"
# ...
list "$path" "$pattern"
```